# Can i burn an Arduino sketch .hex directly using USBASP?

Tags: arduino-uno, uploading, isp, usbasp

I am unable to upload sketches to my Arduino Uno board using the upload option in the IDE. I have done quite a few tests to find the reason but everything seems to be working fine when tested separately. I found that I can program the ATMega328 board when placed on a breadboard using an USBASP progammer and avrdude. So will it work if I burn the .hex generated in Arduino IDE using avrdude and USBASP by placing the ATMega on a breadboard? I would then want to replace the IC on the UNO board back for my application. Thanks for your time and help in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to use the serial bootloader?

Comment: What do you mean by 'serial' bootloader? Actually the problem is that I have ATMega328 instead of 328P for an UNO board. I have tried burning the bootloader fot both 328 and 328P on my 328 but I cant get either of them to program via USB somehow. USB connection is fine as loopback test is running fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can - but you don't even need to remove the chip from the Uno.

The 6 pin header at the end of the board (used for SPI) is also the ISP header for the main chip. Just plug your USBASP into there (you can get adaptors for it for $0.99 off eBay) and program it direct.

I think there's even an option in the IDE's menu to select the USBASP as the programmer (or there used to be on earlier versions).